# System.Data.Sqlite dll different versions return different BOOL values for the same database

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

I have a 'IDataReader' which reads the result of a SQL statement.

```
using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    var boolColumnString = reader[13](or even reader['boolcolumnname']).ToString();
                }
            }
```

This same piece of code is used in both System.Data.SQLite version.

The database is of type .mdc and the 13th column type is `BOOL` with the value set to nothing for all records. It is empty.

However when using the above reader with:

- System.Data.SQLite version 1.0.66 the value of `boolColumnString` is 'false' as it should(cause it makes sense)
- System.Data.SQLite version 1.0.109.2 the value of `boolColumnString` is 'true'

Edit: After a closer look I discovered that there is no check done when you write a TYPE when configuring the table structure. For example you could type "NOTATYPE" and write the changes using the `DB Browser for SQLite` and it would be saved.

As a result of this something strange would probably happen with how the TYPE AFFINITY is checked and result in the 'true/false' result. For now I will stick to allowed types for SQL, but I will still leave the ticket open in case someone understands the issue better.

Comment: You are using ToString() which is creating an empty string which is not null.  An empty string is a string with no character, a null sting is a pointer that points to a null address.  The library fixed a bug that previously was reporting an empty string the same as a null string.

Comment: @jdweng thank you for you explanation. However, I don't think that it describes exactly what happens. Please have a look at my edit. It might make more sense to you than it does to me.